# Mouse suddenly stops working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mouse

I did a current upgrade of my Ubuntu recently. I made basic settings and program installations, and the mouse suddenly stopped working; it does not appear on the screen.

I use a Mousepad and a wireless mouse.

As one of the basic system settings, I installed apps like wps and vlc, set my main screen as font size and installed java, and used these commands:

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

Comment: What kind of mouse do you have? Wired or wireless? If it's a wireless mouse, I would suggest finding a usb mouse and plugging it in. Maybe it will work, and if it does it will make the rest of the troubleshooting easier.